# Details overlaps Last Page Footer

Tags: jasper-reports, reporting

I have a *JasperReports* report with a simple *Detail* with a *Page Footer* and a *Last Page Footer* everything is working OK **but** when there are like 10 records the details overlapps the last page footer. I don't know why..

The report's design in *iReport*
[image]

Detail, Page Footer and Last Page Footer the last Page Footer is 121 height

all elements in last page footer are size-static.

The resulting image in *PDF* format:

[image]

Generals options in report

[image]

my full code. i also try using `uuid` property and not it using getting the same result.

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report1" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="535" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" isSummaryWithPageHeaderAndFooter="true" uuid="9fc4bce9-8dd5-48dd-828c-d598cd0e6faa">
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="2.0"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="497"/>
<style name="Title" forecolor="#FFFFFF" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="50" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Times-Bold"/>
<style name="SubTitle" forecolor="#CCCCCC" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="18" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Times-Roman"/>
<style name="Column header" forecolor="#666666" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="14" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Times-Roman"/>
<style name="Detail" mode="Transparent" fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman"/>
<style name="Row" mode="Transparent" fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman">
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}%2 == 0]]></conditionExpression>
        <style mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0EFEF"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
</style>
<style name="table">
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
</style>
<style name="table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
</style>
<style name="table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
</style>
<style name="table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
</style>
<subDataset name="Table Dataset 1" uuid="3c6a0614-cae1-4fcb-bda5-9407890c397b"/>
<parameter name="logo" class="java.lang.Object" isForPrompting="false"/>
<parameter name="COMPANY_INFO" class="java.lang.Object"/>
<parameter name="doverDetail" class="java.lang.Object"/>
<parameter name="HERA_TYPE" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="MESSAGE" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="lopd" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="cuentaBancaria" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="iva8Total" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="iva8Cuota" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="iva18Total" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="iva18Cuota" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="totalIVA" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="totalALL" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="IVA" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="REDUCEDIVA" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="totalRecordsOnReport" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<queryString language="SQL">
    <![CDATA[]]>
</queryString>
<field name="c02" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="c03" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="c04" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="c05" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="c06" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="c07" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="c08" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="moneySymbol" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="c09" class="java.lang.String"/>
<group name="Group1">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[(int)($V{REPORT_COUNT}/15)]]></groupExpression>
    <groupHeader>
        <band/>
    </groupHeader>
    <groupFooter>
        <band/>
    </groupFooter>
</group>
<group name="Group2">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[(int)($V{REPORT_COUNT}/5)]]></groupExpression>
    <groupHeader>
        <band/>
    </groupHeader>
</group>
<background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</background>
<title>
    <band height="287" splitType="Stretch">
        <image scaleImage="FillFrame" isUsingCache="false">
            <reportElement uuid="32df9772-e5be-4efa-aecd-0fc8ef78a6c6" x="0" y="0" width="210" height="53"/>
            <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{logo}]]></imageExpression>
        </image>
        <frame>
            <reportElement uuid="07211a43-6e91-4f79-8db7-d110e4f25c80" x="0" y="73" width="220" height="145"/>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="bb189484-384e-4bd9-a32b-ceacb0993bb6" x="0" y="0" width="220" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="11" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{COMPANY_INFO}.getC08()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="5b438886-87d6-42e9-8508-f35f9511893b" x="0" y="119" width="220" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{COMPANY_INFO}.getC05()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="29ab4e21-b33e-4431-b69f-aeeca3423a7e" x="0" y="59" width="220" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{COMPANY_INFO}.getC04()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="861ffcbe-6600-4091-b415-ba4ec2dd2948" x="0" y="40" width="220" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{COMPANY_INFO}.getC03()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="9de4a257-f36e-43b1-a79a-962b2466bee1" x="0" y="99" width="220" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["FAX: " + $P{COMPANY_INFO}.getC07()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="ed0d5bf1-40b7-4035-b7c0-8d0c8b7b2666" x="0" y="19" width="220" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="11" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{COMPANY_INFO}.getC02()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="0c35fe89-086b-49b7-93ee-da057344502b" x="0" y="79" width="220" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["TLF: " + $P{COMPANY_INFO}.getC06()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </frame>
        <frame>
            <reportElement uuid="23a78f23-36fb-4425-b1b8-f410ae2ddb8a" x="393" y="72" width="162" height="145"/>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="5b33ab9a-7a2b-42c4-844a-15c2ebde27cd" x="2" y="0" width="158" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{doverDetail}.getC20()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="422a1a0b-c6fc-465e-8dbe-c597ba60dc8a" x="2" y="19" width="158" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{doverDetail}.getCif()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="b0780844-9dd9-4e63-ade3-9812f1bbad66" x="2" y="40" width="160" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{doverDetail}.getC21()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="7134f538-a221-4d08-92c3-f34ceed828a1" x="2" y="59" width="158" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{doverDetail}.getC22()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="480e3be2-049a-4414-b1f9-1dcf0cc76e37" x="4" y="80" width="158" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{doverDetail}.getC23()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </frame>
        <frame>
            <reportElement uuid="87e46bf1-20b8-434a-ac8f-cf37f2d40786" x="305" y="72" width="88" height="145"/>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="98ffc98d-7d8e-4430-bcb4-d50c39ad2492" x="0" y="0" width="88" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Cliente:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="54e05280-9290-4271-a2bb-b12b3ac9bf71" x="0" y="20" width="88" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <text><![CDATA[NIF:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="a32cf285-6324-49a8-84b5-db1d9cda9c74" x="0" y="40" width="88" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Domicilio:]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </frame>
        <frame>
            <reportElement uuid="b47dac3d-b9b3-4679-bd6a-047aa639c146" x="49" y="227" width="100" height="60"/>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="dc473159-0f32-4dd1-bb17-06fc66d69047" x="0" y="20" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <text><![CDATA[N° EXPEDIENTE:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="adff13b9-ded5-464d-b1d5-4657f157a950" x="0" y="39" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <text><![CDATA[FECHA:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField pattern="">
                <reportElement uuid="df66b63a-a0f3-4c09-b832-e26dca95f8bf" x="0" y="-1" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{HERA_TYPE}+":"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </frame>
        <frame>
            <reportElement uuid="97933133-98bf-4fb5-940d-d9b33a04c58d" x="149" y="227" width="337" height="60"/>
            <textField pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="83f50c5c-8c04-42d3-9928-42623bbdcb52" x="3" y="0" width="334" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{doverDetail}.getC02()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="2e722917-4ac1-4eac-bb39-9324b4e6c4f6" x="3" y="19" width="334" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{doverDetail}.getZeusMadrid().getC07()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="11de3751-289f-4b23-8d2a-cf77ccc66d32" x="3" y="39" width="334" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{doverDetail}.getC07()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </frame>
        <textField>
            <reportElement uuid="0599e0d3-6997-4ea1-af8e-10dc073b4a73" x="308" y="0" width="247" height="52"/>
            <textElement>
                <font size="24" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{HERA_TYPE}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</title>
<pageHeader>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</pageHeader>
<columnHeader>
    <band height="21" splitType="Stretch">
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement uuid="6e31a835-24e0-4070-be5b-272e2ea64764" x="0" y="0" width="67" height="20"/>
        </rectangle>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="07bc4a83-82a5-49d6-aa04-4db64d67e710" positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" mode="Transparent" x="1" y="0" width="66" height="20"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
            <text><![CDATA[Código]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement uuid="c76d6b51-5f72-4767-8236-8218b077f0a7" x="68" y="0" width="201" height="20"/>
        </rectangle>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="613c32e5-2375-4a1e-8d45-1edc23697a52" x="66" y="1" width="203" height="20"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
            <text><![CDATA[Concepto]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement uuid="c8f7f5e0-dc87-4cf7-9600-bd570f50e2a9" x="270" y="0" width="57" height="20"/>
        </rectangle>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="7ecea178-eb0b-43ef-b104-94103f79932f" x="270" y="-1" width="56" height="20"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
            <text><![CDATA[Descuento]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement uuid="13a99703-4591-4641-a387-ce78d228ae1d" x="327" y="0" width="51" height="20"/>
        </rectangle>
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement uuid="6a75b86a-f753-4e2b-a94f-a8eb55f1419f" x="379" y="0" width="58" height="20"/>
        </rectangle>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="3f04183d-125c-4f6b-8c1f-2a379d2feba6" x="380" y="0" width="57" height="20"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
            <text><![CDATA[Precio]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement uuid="2d177f3b-7d94-4918-997e-2a8546925581" x="499" y="0" width="56" height="20"/>
        </rectangle>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="d020dae3-edaf-4301-932c-24e6647b9476" x="500" y="0" width="54" height="20"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
            <text><![CDATA[Importe]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="0aad36d1-e15e-40c3-8588-4182829981db" x="327" y="0" width="50" height="20"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
            <text><![CDATA[Cantidad]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement uuid="0aa5a7a9-d1c9-43c7-8089-ab0f13f2117d" x="438" y="0" width="61" height="20"/>
        </rectangle>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="fc0790fd-46ae-44b0-807f-4c1ce75bf470" x="439" y="1" width="60" height="20"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
            <text><![CDATA[IVA]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement uuid="6639fd33-cb59-4bf5-b27a-7749a094c122" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="20"/>
            <graphicElement>
                <pen lineWidth="0.25" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#999999"/>
            </graphicElement>
        </rectangle>
        <frame>
            <reportElement uuid="9d77c3d9-2f02-44d2-93c6-f99cde68428b" positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="20"/>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="b408b0c7-9acb-4483-b44e-a5bda26c126a" x="1" y="0" width="66" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{c07}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="6be3cc4c-54bc-4be5-81f3-58a6bc3c6eea" positionType="Float" x="67" y="0" width="203" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{c03}]]></textFieldExpression>                  
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="2e020377-02d8-461e-a199-c29db17d0b29" x="269" y="0" width="57" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{c06}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="6bae7d73-6f0d-4e89-9bfb-3d248c8ce12e" x="326" y="0" width="52" height="19"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{c02}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="b8ff5333-c098-48d7-9644-0488692a484a" x="378" y="0" width="60" height="19"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{c04}+"€"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="b1c5cdba-013e-4f19-8aac-8459901028b1" x="499" y="0" width="56" height="19"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{c05}+"€"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="e30fffda-ab37-4598-a8ae-95ebf078d621" x="438" y="0" width="62" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{c09}+"%"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </frame>
    </band>
</detail>
<pageFooter>
    <band height="25" splitType="Stretch">
        <frame>
            <reportElement uuid="378a8cc9-ba13-4f2f-8d31-9fae185bf6e4" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="1" width="555" height="24" forecolor="#D0B48E" backcolor="#FFFFFF"/>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement uuid="96e7e0ec-f9a5-431c-8bd2-c7029f8b7811" style="Column header" x="513" y="0" width="40" height="20" forecolor="#000000"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="10" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="8a356ac2-1528-4666-96c4-161db2e45f63" style="Column header" x="433" y="0" width="80" height="20" forecolor="#000000"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="10" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Página "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" de"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="EEEEE dd MMMMM yyyy">
                <reportElement uuid="da6af5ce-a8cb-41a4-8d44-4de6f60a2ba4" style="Column header" x="2" y="1" width="326" height="20" forecolor="#000000"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="10" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Fecha: " +(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy 'Hora:' HH:mm:ss a").format(new java.util.Date()))]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </frame>
    </band>
</pageFooter>
<lastPageFooter>
    <band height="121">
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" evaluationTime="Auto" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement uuid="6f693ef2-89a2-4bda-92c9-3a80bbd2cd75" positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="325" height="78" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <font size="7"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{lopd}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <frame>
            <reportElement uuid="cc4974db-c547-4a54-87ca-352b05efe19f" positionType="Float" x="326" y="0" width="227" height="79"/>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="92ac945a-497b-4ec4-90a2-71414cd1c701" positionType="Float" mode="Transparent" x="1" y="0" width="135" height="10"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font size="7"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Base imponible IVA "+$P{REDUCEDIVA}+" %:"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="aaca6cee-233f-4275-b98f-fea1b2071eeb" positionType="Float" mode="Transparent" x="0" y="10" width="136" height="10"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font size="7"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Cuota IVA "+$P{REDUCEDIVA}+"%:"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="07554459-28b9-41a7-88fb-6f43ec71d163" positionType="Float" mode="Transparent" x="0" y="20" width="136" height="10"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font size="7"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Base imponible IVA "+$P{IVA}+" %:"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="8ec9fffa-ee07-4e1a-8aba-33cf81b43a93" positionType="Float" mode="Transparent" x="0" y="30" width="136" height="10"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font size="7"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Cuota IVA "+$P{IVA}+"%:"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="56c75466-bda7-459f-99bb-6b10c17ed17d" positionType="Float" x="137" y="0" width="89" height="11"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font size="7"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{iva8Total}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="5d0d5daf-1c53-44d1-847b-4ba27223f1bb" positionType="Float" x="137" y="10" width="89" height="11"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font size="7"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{iva8Cuota}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="ff4f94f4-52b1-4d5c-b538-342fbfd6c2ba" positionType="Float" x="137" y="20" width="89" height="11"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font size="7"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{iva18Total}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="06730b02-85fb-4dbd-ba96-9e0e72195cfa" positionType="Float" x="137" y="30" width="89" height="11"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font size="7"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{iva18Cuota}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="1f2001c6-b415-448f-95f5-f3541c2a816d" positionType="Float" mode="Transparent" x="1" y="40" width="135" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <text><![CDATA[TOTAL IVA:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="3560c437-d368-4050-8596-cbf7a105b0c5" positionType="Float" x="137" y="40" width="89" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{totalIVA}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="db9d7d5c-e967-487e-b7a9-999c4c30c4f6" positionType="Float" mode="Transparent" x="1" y="59" width="135" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <text><![CDATA[TOTAL FACTURA:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="ac07ac39-4abb-4083-97b1-77686dbb2221" positionType="Float" x="137" y="59" width="89" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{totalALL}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </frame>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" evaluationTime="Auto" pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement uuid="391ddd7a-801b-4cb9-af07-167678f6089f" positionType="Float" x="0" y="78" width="213" height="23"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{cuentaBancaria}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField evaluationTime="Auto" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement uuid="227f9328-d8d3-464a-8937-d60f779fb585" positionType="Float" x="213" y="78" width="342" height="23"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{MESSAGE}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField pattern="EEEEE dd MMMMM yyyy">
            <reportElement uuid="a7b8b4f6-525e-4db0-ad14-72c2cd44ce04" style="Column header" positionType="Float" x="-1" y="100" width="326" height="20" forecolor="#000000"/>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="10" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Fecha: " +(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy 'Hora:' HH:mm:ss a").format(new java.util.Date()))]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement uuid="e7d1f852-2eb7-4285-a996-1f9eda23cf75" style="Column header" positionType="Float" x="433" y="100" width="80" height="20" forecolor="#000000"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="10" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Página "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" de"]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField evaluationTime="Report">
            <reportElement uuid="bec28c32-19e4-4c24-a170-5edf5a189591" style="Column header" positionType="Float" x="513" y="100" width="40" height="20" forecolor="#000000"/>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="10" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</lastPageFooter>
```

What can i do? Any help is hugely appreciate..

Comment: For all text field you should make stretchWithOverFlow as true.
If problem is still exist, paste your full jrxml code.

Comment: still not working i have past last page footer please let me know if you see something wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i have found the solution on my own was very tricky in fact there is a piece of luck on it.

in my report i have checked the option `Summary With page Header and Footer` `selected true`.

`Summary With page Header and Footer` according to the `DOCS`

[image]

to solve my problem i have `uncheck this option` and everything works ok. Seems Jasper tries to print the Footer `LastPageFooter` in this case even when shouldn't and there is not space on it.

my working `Options`

[image]

i really hope can help somebody.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code for last page footer.

```
<lastPageFooter>
    <band height="121">
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" evaluationTime="Auto" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement uuid="6f693ef2-89a2-4bda-92c9-3a80bbd2cd75" positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="325" height="78" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <font size="7"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{lopd}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <frame>
            <reportElement uuid="cc4974db-c547-4a54-87ca-352b05efe19f" positionType="Float" x="326" y="0" width="227" height="79"/>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="92ac945a-497b-4ec4-90a2-71414cd1c701" positionType="Float" mode="Transparent" x="1" y="0" width="135" height="10"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font size="7"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Base imponible IVA "+$P{REDUCEDIVA}+" %:"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="aaca6cee-233f-4275-b98f-fea1b2071eeb" positionType="Float" mode="Transparent" x="0" y="10" width="136" height="10"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font size="7"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Cuota IVA "+$P{REDUCEDIVA}+"%:"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="07554459-28b9-41a7-88fb-6f43ec71d163" positionType="Float" mode="Transparent" x="0" y="20" width="136" height="10"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font size="7"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Base imponible IVA "+$P{IVA}+" %:"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="8ec9fffa-ee07-4e1a-8aba-33cf81b43a93" positionType="Float" mode="Transparent" x="0" y="30" width="136" height="10"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font size="7"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Cuota IVA "+$P{IVA}+"%:"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="56c75466-bda7-459f-99bb-6b10c17ed17d" positionType="Float" x="137" y="0" width="89" height="11"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font size="7"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{iva8Total}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="5d0d5daf-1c53-44d1-847b-4ba27223f1bb" positionType="Float" x="137" y="10" width="89" height="11"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font size="7"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{iva8Cuota}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="ff4f94f4-52b1-4d5c-b538-342fbfd6c2ba" positionType="Float" x="137" y="20" width="89" height="11"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font size="7"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{iva18Total}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="06730b02-85fb-4dbd-ba96-9e0e72195cfa" positionType="Float" x="137" y="30" width="89" height="11"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font size="7"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{iva18Cuota}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="1f2001c6-b415-448f-95f5-f3541c2a816d" positionType="Float" mode="Transparent" x="1" y="40" width="135" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <text><![CDATA[TOTAL IVA:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="3560c437-d368-4050-8596-cbf7a105b0c5" positionType="Float" x="137" y="40" width="89" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{totalIVA}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="db9d7d5c-e967-487e-b7a9-999c4c30c4f6" positionType="Float" mode="Transparent" x="1" y="59" width="135" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <text><![CDATA[TOTAL FACTURA:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="ac07ac39-4abb-4083-97b1-77686dbb2221" positionType="Float" x="137" y="59" width="89" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{totalALL}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </frame>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" evaluationTime="Auto" pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement uuid="391ddd7a-801b-4cb9-af07-167678f6089f" positionType="Float" x="0" y="78" width="213" height="23"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{cuentaBancaria}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField evaluationTime="Auto" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement uuid="227f9328-d8d3-464a-8937-d60f779fb585" positionType="Float" x="213" y="78" width="342" height="23"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{MESSAGE}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField pattern="EEEEE dd MMMMM yyyy">
            <reportElement uuid="a7b8b4f6-525e-4db0-ad14-72c2cd44ce04" style="Column header" positionType="Float" x="-1" y="100" width="326" height="20" forecolor="#000000"/>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="10" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Fecha: " +(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy 'Hora:' HH:mm:ss a").format(new java.util.Date()))]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement uuid="e7d1f852-2eb7-4285-a996-1f9eda23cf75" style="Column header" positionType="Float" x="433" y="100" width="80" height="20" forecolor="#000000"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="10" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Página "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" de"]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField evaluationTime="Report">
            <reportElement uuid="bec28c32-19e4-4c24-a170-5edf5a189591" style="Column header" positionType="Float" x="513" y="100" width="40" height="20" forecolor="#000000"/>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="10" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</lastPageFooter>
```

Comment: seems doing the same thing.

Comment: post your whole jrxml file.